# htacess with different rule for jpg/png/gif without knowing the mime based on uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using url shortner and want to redirect with htaccess. I am able to achieve a similar effect with php, however I would rather Apache handle the rewrite

Here's an example of what I have

www.site.com/s/sdfa5qT3z
www.site.com/m/sdfa5qT3z 
www.site.com/l/sdfa5qT3z 
etc

which should redirect to 
www.site.com/public/images/small/sdfa5qT3z.jpg
www.site.com/public/images/medium/sdfa5qT3z.jpg
www.site.com/public/images/large/sdfa5qT3z.jpg
respectively

If all images are .jpg this is no problem at all, however I have a mix of .jpg, .png and .gif

Problem is I do not know the mime/type based on the original url before redirect

Is there a rule or series of rules I can run to test if
file exists if I add .jpg 
if not test if .png exists
and finally if .gif exists.

Which ever rule passes we rewrite and stop checking subsequent rules. If all these fail then 404

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^s/ - [E=size:small]
RewriteRule ^m/ - [E=size:medium]
RewriteRule ^l/ - [E=size:large]
RewriteRule ^(s|m|l)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ - [E=image_url:$2]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/images/%{ENV:size}/%{ENV:image_url}.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(s|m|l)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /public/images/%{ENV:size}/%{ENV:image_url}.jpg

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/images/%{ENV:size}/%{ENV:image_url}.png -f
RewriteRule ^(s|m|l)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /public/images/%{ENV:size}/%{ENV:image_url}.png

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/images/%{ENV:size}/%{ENV:image_url}.gif -f
RewriteRule ^(s|m|l)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /public/images/%{ENV:size}/%{ENV:image_url}.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

This *could* be done in `.htaccess` only, but I think it would be tedious and repetitive. You'd be better off checking the request URI and, if it matches, sending it off to a PHP file that can determine if the image exists or not.

Here's an example:

**Document root `.htaccess`:**

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([sml])/(\w+)/?$ image-redirect.php?size=$1&code=$2 [L]
```

**Document root `image-redirect.php`:**

```php
<?php

// Set the valid sizes
$validSizes = [
    's' => 'small',
    'm' => 'medium',
    'l' => 'large',
];

// Set the valid extensions
$validExtensions = 'jpg|png|gif';

// Get query string data
$size = $validSizes[$_GET['size']];
$code = $_GET['code'];

// Loop through each extension to check if the file exists
foreach (explode('|', $validExtensions) as $extension) {
    // Set the file name relative to this file
    $currentFile = "public/images/$size/$code.$extension";

    if (file_exists($currentFile)) {
        // If it exists, redirect with 302 status code.
        // To make permanent, use header("Location: /$currentFile", true, 301); instead.
        header("Location: /$currentFile");
    }
}

// If it doesn't exist, say so with a 404 HTTP header.
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
print "File does not exist.";
```